# Maximum length exceeded - JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

Why am I getting this error? I have and html that is returned from web method, when html content have more content length than I get this error:

> "Message":"Maximum length exceeded.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 1):

How big is the content?

You can try and increase the JSONN serialization limit:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: I am not using web service so cant use webServices node.

Comment: So what are you using? Can you share some code?
I assumed you were using web services: "I have and html that is returned from web method"